# How to delete a c++ pointer in objective c with ARC

Tags: objective-c, interop, objective-c++

I'm wrapping the box2d library and I want to properly dealloc the b2World pointer when the wrapper deallocates. My question is, should I override the -dealloc method in objective c, or does ARC automatically deallocate the c++ *world pointer?

```
#import "World.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
@interface World()
@property b2World* world;

@end

@implementation World 
@synthesize world;

-(void) createWorld:(Vec2*) gravity{
    b2Vec2 g(gravity.x, gravity.y);
    world = new b2World(g);
}
-(void) dealloc{
    delete world;
    world = nil;
    NSString *temp = @"World DEALLOCATED!!";
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
}
```

Did I properly implement -(void) dealloc or is it unnecessary to do so?

Comment: Keep your `dealloc`, there is no ARC for C++ classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC does not automatically count references on c++ pointers. You did properly implement `dealloc`, though you may want to check to make sure `world` isn't `0` before calling `delete` on it.

Comment: Calling `delete` and `delete[]` on `0` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is it? I seem to remember getting crashes on `delete 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading through this article. He goes through some gotchas and some typical practices to help with understanding this:

http://coherent-labs.com/blog/objective-c-arc-gotchas/

Basically: It seems ARC only manages objects that adhere to the reference counting structure of Obj-C. C++ objects are not allocated with the same allocation methods Obj-C objects use, thus C++ objects don't have reference counting thus ARC does not manage them.